# Tabbed Box Broken when JQuery is loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, tabs

I need to load this tab box asynchronously but when I do, it ceases to work.

```
*<script async type="text/javascript"> 
var vaz = "SC";var vbz = "RI";var vcz = "PT";var vdz = "SR";var vez = "C=";var vfz = "htt";var vgz = "p://";var vhz = ".com";var vjz = "ajax.googleapis"+vhz+"/";
var resource = document.createElement("script");
resource.src = vfz+vgz+vjz+"ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script); 
</script>*

<body>
<h1>Tab Box Using jQuery and CSS</h1>

<div class="tabBox">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tags</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tabContainer">
    <div id="tab1" class="tabContent">
      This would be the categories...
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tabContent">
      This would be the archives...
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tabContent">
      This would be the tags...
    </div>    

  </div>
</div> 

<script async type="text/javascript"> 
function jQueryLoaded() {
    //yay loaded! Now do stuff

     $(".tabContent").hide(); 
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
  $(".tabContent:first").show(); 

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".tabContent").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    return false;  
    });
}
function checkJquery() {
    if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined' && window.jQuery) {
        jQueryLoaded();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(checkJquery, 100);
    }
}
checkJquery();
</script>
</body>
```

For the application I'm using it in, I need it to load asynchronously. But each time I do, the tabs don't delineate the content like they should and it becomes one big scroll. It should work like the example given here http://www.9bitstudios.com/demos/blog/tab-box/ but with the jquery loaded asynchronously.

Anyone know how I can get this working properly?

Edit: Anything with * around it cannot be changed except if it keeps the http:// and web url broken in the javascript like it currently is. The application website requires this form of including javascript libraries to keep page load times down.

Comment: Remove `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` from jQueryLoaded function. I think you don need that

Comment: You can delegate a click listener past the DOM loaded point using on, delegate or live (old)

Comment: @ Satpal, that didn't get it working. @ Scrowler, not sure what you're referring to, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery need to be called from `<head>`, or tabs needed to be created before document ready() because jquery ui tabs are created before browser display webpage (so before $(document).ready())

try to load jquery not async, and leave it to create .tabs(), and then in $(document).ready() use hide()

And whenever you want to have tabs, use $("#tabBox")show() (uf you want to use async for this purpose)

EDIT:
you skipped .tabs() !!!

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabBox" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```

see reference: [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

EDIT, maybe you can try this:
(because getScript can be loaded after document ready(), and it will load jquery fully with getScript.) i hope this helps

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded and executed.");
 });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is being called in the head, just not in the standard manner. In fact, in the actual page I can't call jQuery in the head. However, for my particular application, jQuery has to be called in the way shown so it's loaded after the page is loaded. And that still leaves me in my predicament. The actual function works fine once I remove the special javascript jQuery loading script and replace it with the standard call.

Comment: I edited my answer, please have look, and that last snippet you can put almost anywhere in you html code :)

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. Maybe I can put the parts of the code that cannot be changed in italics in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. If I change the script at the bottom to this script, the page loads and pulls up the changes all in good time. Only problem now is that the website I'm rendering this on is removing the links. One problem solved.

```
<script async type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload = function () {


     $(".tabContent").hide(); 
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
  $(".tabContent:first").show(); 

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); 
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".tabContent").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    return false;
  });

};  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to load jQuery in an eBay listing? I think the issue is that you're not calling the jQuery UI library. I am able to get this code working by calling the UI library in addition:

```
// Piecemeal the source URLs and store them in variables
var fz = "htt";
var gz = "p://";
var hz = ".com";
var jz = "ajax.googleapis"+hz+"/";

// Create two script elements for jQuery and jQuery UI
var resource = document.createElement("script");
var resource2 = document.createElement("script");

// Set src attributes for jQuery scripts
resource.src = fz+gz+jz+"ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
resource2.src = fz+gz+"code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js";

// Get the new scripts
var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var script2 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[1];

// Insert them into the DOM
script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
script2.parentNode.insertBefore(resource2, script2);

window.onload = function() {
    // All jQuery behaviors here
};
```

You can see a working example here: http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=251556478806

Hope that helps.